# How to make use of Try and Catch for setting values

Tags: c#, validation, exception, try-catch

How I can get a try catch inside `Letter` to invoke a try catch inside `Program`? At the moment I am using a bool as a validator but I want any false bool to throw a error and for `Program` to see this.

What's the best way to do this, because at the moment `Program` can't tell if a property has been set incorrectly.

`Program.cs`

```
        Letter a = new Letter();
        try
        {
            a.StoredChar = '2';
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            a.StoredChar = 'a';
        }
        // I want this to print 'a' because the '2' should throw a catch somehow
        // I don't know how to set this up.
        Console.WriteLine(a.StoredChar);
```

`Letter.cs`

```
    class Letter
    {
        char storedChar;

        public char StoredChar
        {
            set { validateInput(value);}
            get { return storedChar;}
        }

        bool validateInput(char x)
        {
            if ( ( (int)x >= 65 && (int)x <= 90 ) || ( (int)x >= 97 && (int)x <= 122 )  )
            {
                storedChar = x;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The real problem here is: Is the '2' really an unexpected value or are you using exceptions to drive you program flow?

Comment: '2' is an unexpected value, this will be driven by user input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just throw exception in Letter class. Smth like this:

```
private void validateInput(char x)
{
    if ( ( (int)x >= 65 && (int)x <= 90 ) || ( (int)x >= 97 && (int)x <= 122 )  )
    {
       storedChar = x;
    }
    else
    {
       throw new OutOfRangeException("Incorrect letter!");
    }
}
```

Comment: this. just do this. and don't bother returning `false` if you're just going to throw the value away...

Comment: If I write `catch (Exception e)` in Program, how can I print the "Incorrect exception" part? If I print e I get a lot of extra information more than the string...

Comment: @Joseph `Console.WriteLine(e.Message);`

Answer (score 4):

I would never use exceptions to drive the program flow. If the user is allowed to type values that can be incorrectly passed to the Letter class then you should change you class to make the  ValidateInput method public and call it before trying to change the StoredChar

```
char z = '2';
Letter a = new Letter();
if(!a.ValidateInput(z))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid data");
    return;
}
a.StoredChar = z;
```

Comment: In my example the unexpected input would be from a user, is this still a bad case of using try.. catch?

Comment: Yes, I thinnk that, sooner or later, you will need a procedure to check the user inputs before adding them to your class.

Comment: @Joseph throwing an exception, and catching it, adds unnecessary overhead. If you don't need to, then don't do it. Exceptions should only be thrown when the application encounters something exceptional. More info available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms998547.aspx#scalenetchapt05_topic24)

Comment: @alexw, good point, that is another thing to consider. Exception slow down in a noticeable way the code execution.

Comment: Cheers, I did not realise it was a big slow down.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using `try catch` to set the value is a good idea but based on your requirement I think the setter can be like this:

```
void validateInput(char x)
{
   if (((int)x >= 65 && (int)x <= 90 ) || ((int)x >= 97 && (int)x <= 122))
        {
            storedChar = x;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new SomeException();
        }
}
```

Comment: dont know why my answer is down voted. But for anyone who think it's OK for using try catch as logic, please refer to this post: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/107723/arguments-for-or-against-using-try-catch-as-logical-operators

Comment: Is `SomeException()` a method? If you are trying to call a constructor then you should use `throw new SomeException();`